# Uploading a file to AWS S3 Bucket from Remote Server using PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am very new to AWS. I am trying to upload a file to S3 bucket using PHP SDK.
My web application is hosted with another provider (not AWS).

Following is my code:

```
$this->client = new S3Client([
    'region' => $this->params->get('aws')['region'],
    'version' => $this->params->get('aws')['version'],
    'credentials  ' => [
        'key'    => $this->params->get('aws')['credentials']['access_key'],
        'secret' => $this->params->get('aws')['credentials']['secret_key']
    ]
]);

$result = $this->client->putObject([
    'Bucket' => $this->params->get('aws')['bucket_name'],
    'Key' => $path.'/'.$this->generateFileKey(),
    'ACL' => 'private'
]);

return $result;
```

This returns an error.

> Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata service. (cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 1008 milliseconds (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/)

All my access keys are correct and the version is `latest`.

I tried all the examples here and the documentation. But I can not figure out why i am getting this error.

Is my code wrong or do I have to do changes to my AWS bucket?

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing valid AWS credentials in the client? You might want to print those values and check what it shows. Alternatively, you can provide credentials in a config file by using the AWS CLI `aws configure` command and supplying your AWS Access Key and Secret Key. See: [Configuration and credential file settings - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html)

Comment: It appears to be falling back to using the machine identity for authentication - but your host is not in AWS, hence the call to the instance profile service is failing. Shouldn't there be a 'token' along with the 'key' and 'secret'?

Comment: `'credentials  '` is incorrect.  Note the extra spaces.  Because of this, the SDK has no credentials, and is falling back to trying to load them from the (non existent) metadata server.  Remove the extra spaces and it'll probably work.

Comment: @AnonCoward - Thank You for pointing that out. That was the issue. :)